# C# WPF DataGrid is not updated when binded to the DataTable programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

`DataGrid` is not updated when `ItemsSource` bound programmatically to the `DataTable`.

I'm building a user control that can change its inner content by the condition (via MVVM).
**Xaml example:**

```
<Window ...>
    <grid x:Name="mainGrid" />
</Window>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel mvm { get; set; } = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = mvm;

        var dataGrid = new DataGrid()
        {
            Width = 400,
            Height = 400,
            AutoGenerateColumns = true,
            IsReadOnly = true,
        };

        var binding = new Binding("DefaultView")
        {
            Source = mvm.TableSource,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(dataGrid, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

        mainGrid.Children.Add(dataGrid);
    }

    private void button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mvm.TableSource.Columns.Add("test" + new Random().Next());
        mvm.TableSource.Rows.Add("test" + new Random().Next());
        mvm.Refresh(); //force update
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel code:**

```
public class MainViewModel:ModelBase // ModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DataTable TableSource {get;set;} = new DataTable()

    public void Refresh()
    {
        var temp = TableSource;
        TableSource = null;
        OnPropertyChanged("TableSource");
        TableSource = temp;
        OnPropertyChanged("TableSource");
    }
}
```

I expect to see the contents of the `DataTable` when it bound programmatically to the `DataGrid` (only empty rows are added in this case), but it only works properly when it bound via `XAML`. Any ideas what I could probably miss?

Comment: Firing `OnPropertyChanged("TableSource")` would only have an effect if you would bind to a `TableSource` property, which you aren't doing.

Comment: `var binding = new Binding("TableSource.DefaultView");`. The DataContext is already `mvm` so don't bother setting `Source`. `UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged` is pointless because `ItemsSource` is not able to update the source property. Did you expect it to give you a new `DataTable` or something? You can delete a lot of no-op stuff in `Refresh()`, too. `TableSource` should raise PropertyChanged itself in its setter, or else make the setter private. You're asking for trouble this way.

Comment: @Ed the idea seems to be not to replace the TableSource instance, which would be necessary with an ordinary setter with PropertyChanged.

Comment: @Clemens Ohh, I see. My mind added a phantom `new` somewhere. I get it now.

Comment: @Clemens, Indeed it somehow works when you binding it via xaml like this `ItemsSource= { Binding TableSource.DefaultView`, `UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged } `and firing `OnPropertyChanged("TableSource")` . Is there any way to get the same effect in the code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clean how to imitate the same functionality in code, so I added a workaround where the columns are added before the actual binding.